# Why does sizeof() operator return different output for static and dynamic array?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, sizeof

Please see the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int *arr2;

    arr2=malloc(10*sizeof(int));

    printf("The size of arr is %lu \n", sizeof(arr));
    printf("The sice of arr2 is %lu \n", sizeof(arr2));
    return 0;

}
```

The output is :

```
The size of arr is 40  
The sice of arr2 is 8
```

I know that `arr` contains the address of first element in the array.
My question is: Why does `sizeof()` operator returns 40 for `arr`, and 8 for `arr2`?
How come `sizeof(arr)` is 40, as it just stores the address of first element of the array?

Comment: How big is `sizeof (a_pointer)`?

Comment: Because `sizeof(int[10])` and `sizeof(int*)` are different.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   `sizeof(pointer)`  is 8

Comment: What is `sizeof (arr2)`? -- look identical? (they are and that's why...)

Comment: `arr2` is a pointer, not a dynamic array.  `arr` does not "contains the address of first element in the array" nor "stores the address of first element of the array".  `arr` is an array.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  I alloted memory to `arr2` using `malloc`. So it is a dynamic array.

Comment: [`int *arr2`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr%5B10%5D%3B) remains a "pointer to int" as defined by C and thus it has the size of a pointer..  C does not specify a _dynamic array_.  You may use pointer `arr2` in various ways  and call it whatever you want

Comment: `arr` **does not** store an address value; the expression gets *converted* to an address value *unless* it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators.  `arr` **is** an array, and `sizeof arr == sizeof (int [10])`.  `arr2` is a pointer, and `sizeof arr2 == sizeof (int *)` and `sizeof *arr2 == sizeof (int)`.  It stores the address of a *single* `int` object, which *may* be the first element of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` does not contain the address of the first element of the array.  `arr` **is** the array.  It just decays to a pointer to the first element *in most contexts*.

One of the few times an array name does not decay is when it is the subject of the `sizeof` operator.  In that case, `sizeof` evaluates to the size of the array in bytes which in this case is 40.

`arr2` on the other hand is a pointer to an `int`, so using `sizeof` on it gives you the size of the pointer which on your system is 8.  It doesn't matter if it points to a dynamically allocated array, the start of a local array, or somewhere in the middle of either.  The only thing `sizeof` looks at is the type of its operand.  In fact, unless its operand is a variable length array, `sizeof` is evaluated a compile time.

Comment: If I give      int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};  and print   *arr,  it prints 1.   So arr contains the address of first element of the array

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula For any array or pointer `arr` and index `i`, the expression `arr[i]` is exactly equal to `*(arr + i)`. From that follows that `*arr` is the same as `arr[0]`. You can't use that as evidence that arrays are pointers.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula It does **not**.  Arrays and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Also see [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Keep in mind that the `sizeof` operator evaluates to the size of the **type** of its operand. The type of `arr` is `int[10]`. The type of `arr2` is `int*`. These two types have different sizes, and that's what `sizeof` evaluates to.

Comment: `arr2` is malloc'ed. So `arr2` is an array of size 40 (10 elements).  So its size should be 40. Isn't it??

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula `arr2` is not malloc'ed. It only points to memory that has been malloc'ed. As I already said,`sizeof` gives you the size of the type of its operand. `arr2`'s type is `int*`, so `sizeof(arr2)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula `int *arr2;` defines `arr2` as a ***pointer*** to `int`. You can make it point to the first element of an array, but it's still a *pointer*.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula To better understand pointers I recommend you take a pen and apiece of paper. Draw two boxes on the paper. Label one `arr2`, and draw an arrow from that box to the other. That's really how pointers work, and might help you understand why `arr2` is not in itself an array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I agree. But it becomes an array, after alloting memory using `malloc`.  What I understood is-----> this information is not available at compile time, so we  
 get different output.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula It does not "become" an array.  `arr2` is a pointer and always will be.  It just happens to point to a dynamic array in your case, however `sizeof` doesn't care about that.  It only cares that `arr2` is a `int *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  `sizeof` is a compile tiime operator.  So, it does not know about the memory, we alloted using malloc. I feel this is a resonable explanation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  At compile time, `sizeof`  does not have enough  information about  `arr2` . It  only sees,  `arr2` as a pointer to `int` at compile time.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula C is a statically typed language. No variable can ever change type at runtime. `arr2` is an `int*`. This will always be the case, no matter what you assign to it. `malloc()` allocates memory and gives you a pointer to the first byte of that memory. Just because you assign that pointer to `arr2` does not change the type of `arr2`. It will continue to be of type `int*`.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula:  `sizeof` has all the information it needs about `arr2` at compile time. `arr2` is a pointer - at runtime it *may* point to the first element of an array, or it may point to a single `int` that isn’t part of an array, or it may not point to anything at all.  That has no effect on its *size*, any more than storing different values to an `int` object changes its size.  `sizeof arr2` gives you the size of the pointer, not what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Because types are different in your case (int [10] vs int *). If you keep the types same, both will return same number.

Nit: instead of lu, use zu to print size_t.

Moral: sizeof is not a function but an operator.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is an operator that will get the size of a type that can be resolved at compile time. the compiler does not know what `malloc` will return. it only sees the types `int arr[10];` and `int *arr;` and returns the size of the type on the current platform